# Change element array position to top

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have this function in NodeJS where i filter elements:

```
// Remove duplicates and expired
var data = (result[0].concat(result[1]).concat(result[3])).filter((event, index, self) => self.findIndex((t) => {
                    var eventDate = new Date(event.start_time);
                    return t.id === event.id && todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) <= eventDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                }) === index)

                // Remove invalid
                .filter(function(event){
                    if(~this.indexOf(event.id)){
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, result[2])

                // Sort array by date
                .sort(function(a,b) {
                    return new Date(a.start_time).getTime() - new Date(b.start_time).getTime();
                })

                // Filter promoted
                // PROBLEM
                .filter(function(event){
                    if(~this.indexOf(event.id)){
                        event.promoted = true;
                        console.log(filtered.indexOf(event));
                        // MOVE THIS TO TOP
                    }
                    return true;
                }, result[4]);
```

Now, in the last filter method I'm finding elements with ID from the lis(result [4]) and add to them property "promoted".

I also wanted to move all promoted events immediatly to the top of array since i have their index in array instead of firing another loop to this job.

How can i do this? Because using splice for me didn't work

Also any suggestion on quality of this function?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show a simple data set with your sequence of `filter.sort.filter` along with the expected output?

Comment: Your sort function should return `-1`, `0`, and `1` if it's going to work reliably

Comment: `.sort` does mutate the input array, just so you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `filter` to change elements of array. There is `map` for that.

If you want to sort elements based on more than one property you could do it like this.

```
//clean
const invalid = result[2],
    promoted = result[4];

var data = result[0]
   .concat(result[1], result[3])
   .filter(dedup) //remove duplicated
   //set promoted flag
   .map(event => {
       event.promoted = promoted.indexOf(event.id) > -1
       return event
   })
   //sort by promoted then by start_time  
   .sort((a, b) => (b.promoted - a.promoted) || (a.start_time - b.start_time))
```